# How to access internal variables of a microcontroller in real-time during testing phase?

Tags: testing, embedded

I am working on an embedded project with a microcontroller (F28379D). In the development phase, internal variables can be accessed using a debugger while connecting to the serial port. But in the testing phase, how do I have access some of the internal variables?

In automotive projects, there are a2l variables that give the real-time information of variables/signals and can be added into ControlDesk or AutomationDesk projects (for dSPACE rigs) during testing phase.

But for a microcontroller like F28379D, how do I access these internal variables. I understand that some variables can be transmitted via CAN and read on the trace. But is there a file that has to be created like a2l to be able to access these?

I am a software tester who has worked in the automotive industry previously. But currently working with a small team of embedded engineers. I'm trying to understand if there are files that the software development team needs to create for the tester to be able to access required information. As a small team, we don't have access to major industry standard software present in automotive and hence wondering if there are equivalent software tools or files in order to get this information.

Thank you in advance!

In my previous experience I worked with large software teams that had access to automotive files such as a2l, odx, as input to my simulations for testing. But currently I don't have access to the internal signals unless all the required variables are added into CAN messages or be connected via the debugger of the launchpad which can be impractical while working with multiple launchpads.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your previous projects, exposure of any "internal variables" was not a function of the microcontroller, but of whatever software was running on the microcontroller.  So it is not a matter of what MCU you are using, but rather of the software interfaces _your_ software team have made available.  It would be naive to assume the kind of interfaces available "as standard" in one industry were available in an entirely different domain.  You need to talk to your software development team about test requirements.  Most likely any support will be entirely proprietory and of their design.

Comment: In addition to what Clifford correctly says,it is often necessary to separate "white box" and "black box" testing.You can devise unit tests which run parts of the code in a hosted environment where you can access the internal variables, and system level tests which simply cannot access the them.At this level you will have to infer the value of the internal variables from the externally visible behaviour of the system.This requires a change of methodology,not just expecting the software to be designed to let you test the way you are used to(although some level of design-for-test is reasonable).

Comment: Either you have to develop tests as part of the product, or you have to run the tests on-chip in some test build using an in-circuit debugger.

Comment: @Clifford What are the interfaces that can be developed by the software development team? I'm new to this domain so any information would be valuable.

Comment: The automotive industry has open standards for that sort of thing that I assume you are referring to.  In the absence of any industry standards, your software team are likely to have implemented their own proprietary support for test, development and debug, or possibly nothing at all.  You are asking here when you should be asking your own team, or refering to your own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are still interested.

The A2L file you worked with previously would have been generated as part of the SW build.  It basically tells an XCP tool details of variables you want to be able to measure, or parameters you want to be able to change (Calibrate).
It extracts the addresses of these variable and parameters from the .map file (Or .elf file).
For this to work the SW has to be setup to work with XCP.  Calibration parameters are usually in the Flash, which cannot easily be changed on the fly.  So you would normally have copies allocated space in RAM.  The A2L file would have the addresses of the items in RAM which can then be manipulated by the XCP tool.  But it's more complicated than that as there are several different ways of doing this flash/RAM exchange.  The key thing is the SW has to be developed to support XCP.  If it isn't then you will really struggle to do what you are trying to do.  Or the SW team will need to create a different type of interface.